# Powershell: How can i automate importing a new module from a script?

Tags: powershell

I have a module that lives in a shared network directory ex; `"\\private\Shell.ps1"`, I have a script I'm running from my local machine which is doing something like:

```
Import-Module -Name \\private\Shell.ps1
Login-ShellCustomCommand -CredCert $cert
```

but the problem is `Import-Module -Name \\private\Shell.ps1` opens up a new powershell instance and it never runs the `Login-ShellCustomCommand -CredCert $cert` command and instead waits for me to manually put it.

Copying the whole directory to my local machine is not an option since there is a very large amount of data present in `\\private\`. Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: `. \\private\Shell.ps1` i.e. invoke the script using [Dot sourcing operator .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#dot-sourcing-operator-) instead of `Import-Module`.